# Algorithm Big Omega

Tags: big-o

I am having trouble analyzing the following.

```
for b = 1 to n
     for u =  b to n
        for i = b to u
            Print
```

I am having trouble determining the worst-case runtime.
The first loop runs n times, the second loop runs (n(n+1))/2 times.
I then beleive that the third loop runs (n+1)/2 times.

However I have been told that it has a runtime of O(n^3).
Therefore it's best-case runtime can't be greater then the worst-case runtime!
I'm hoping for a push in the right direction if possible!
Thanks!

Comment: The minimum and maximum runtime of these loops are always equal! Btw, we use to say best-case and worst-case rather than minimum or maximum. Also, you are making a confusion between minimum/maximum and the Omega/O notation.

Comment: The third loop quite clearly doesn't run (n+1)/2 times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The third loop executes Print **u-b+1** times {3} when it is activated.

When the second loop is activated, the third loop is activated for all u from b to n, i.e. executes Print 1+2+3+...n-b+1 times (substitute u=1, 2, 3...n in {3}). Using the formula for [triangular numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number), this count equals **(n-b+1)(n-b+2)/2** {2}.

When the first loop is activated, the second loop is activated for all b from 1 to n, i.e. executes Print n(n+1)/2 + (n-1)n/2 + (n-2)(n-1)/2 + ... 1 times (substitute b= 1, 2, 3... n in {2}; the counts are decreasing).

Using the formula for [tetrahedral numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetrahedral_number), this equals **n(n+1)(n+2)/6** {1}.

If you have trouble with this approach, you can simulate the Prints by hand instead.

For n=1

```
*
```

For n=2

```
*
* *

*
```

For n=3

```
*
* *
* * *

*
* *

*
```

For n=4

```
*
* *
* * *
* * * *

*
* *
* * *

*
* *

*
```

...

You clearly see the pattern of triangles of decreasing size. The area of the triangles grows as the square of the side. **The total volume grows as the cube of the side**.